# How does 32bit applications run on 64bit Mac?

Tags: macos, architecture, x86, 64-bit

I am trying to gather some details about how its possible that 32 bit applications work/run on 64 bit Mac and thus will assembly code written considering 64 bit work?

Comment: Related: [How does OS X run 64-bit Binaries while running on a 32-bit Kernel?](https://superuser.com/q/340549/499711)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is very vague.  I'll try to clear things up somewhat:

Any recent Mac has a processor that supports both 32-bit and 64-bit execution modes.

The OS X kernel can run in either 32- or 64-bit mode on such a processor.  In 10.6 and earlier, the default was for the kernel to run in 32-bit mode.  In 10.7, the kernel runs in 64-bit mode by default.

An application and its related libraries can support running in either 32-bit, 64-bit or both.  This is completely separate from whether or not the kernel is running in 64-bit (that is: you can run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit kernel, and you can run 32-bit applications on a 64-bit kernel).

The net effect of this is that you can write your code for either 32-bit or 64-bit, and it will work, regardless of what the kernel is doing.  That said, your application must be in sync with itself; you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit code within a single process.

Comment: Thanks. Your response is almost what I am looking for. Ya I know my question is very vague. I am just starting on assembly & and need to have better understanding of writing assembly code in 64bit & 32bit kernels.